# Is $P(U=u)=1/x$ well defined when $x$ is the values a discrete random variable takes

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $X$ is a discrete random variable with the following probability distribution function
$P(X=x)=c(x-1),x=2,3,4,5,6$ where $c$ is the normalizing constant.

Now let $U$ be a discrete uniform random variable such that :
$P(U=u)=1/x,u=1,2,\dots ,x( x$ is the value taken by $X$)

I was wondering if $P(U=u)$ is well-defined in the sense that $P(U=u)=1/x$ defined above makes sense?
How can the probability that a random variable $U$ take the value $u$ be random?

If I fix  $x=2$ then $P(U=1)=P(U=2)=1/2$ , but then for $X=3$ we get $P(U=1)=P(U=2)=P(U=3)=1/3$ . How can we reconcile the two?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd read this as a conditional probability, namely:  $$P(U=u\,|\,X=x)=\frac 1x$$

Note that, given $X=x$, $U$ is permitted to take $x$ values so the sum of the conditional probabilities is $1$ as it should be.

To gain intuition for the set up, imagine that you first throw a fair die and record its value $X$.  Then you toss a coin $X$ times and let $Y$ be the number of Heads you see.  Then of course the distribution of $Y$ depends on $X$.  For example:$$P(Y=0\,|\,X=3)=\frac 1{2^3}$$  while $$P(Y=0\,|\,X=6)=\frac 1{2^6}$$ 
and, in general, $$P(Y=0\,|\,X=x)=\frac 1{2^x}$$